# Xcode enable file access by default

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode11, macos-catalina

Since upgrading to macOS Catalina every time I run a Xcode project I get this dialog window:

[image]

Is there a way to enable the access by default or disable this security feature, so that I don't have to press this very time?

Comment: Is this one particular project, or every project? I've never seen that window for Xcode. But I would _expect_ to see that window for a mac app running from Xcode, because, you know, sandboxing.

Comment: This happens on all projects even those that don't access files at all. The projects are all simple command line tools in C++ I don't know if this happens on other languages

Comment: Code sign your project. Once you allow access the first time, the setting will be remembered (macOS will see it as a new version instead of a completely new binary)

Comment: @TheNextman ok, which settings do I need to change? I don't have an developer account

Comment: You need a developer account. I believe the free level is sufficient for signing code to run locally.

Comment: @TheNextman wait don't you have to pay to get an developer account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are re-prompted every time you recompile your application because the OS sees it as a brand new binary every time. If you code sign your binary, the OS will recognize the unchanging signature and consider the binary to be the "same" (and thus, remember your privacy choices)

From [Code Signing Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html):

> Shipping and Updating Your Product
> The user’s system considers the new version of your product to be the same program as the previous version. For example, Keychain Services does not distinguish older and newer versions of your program as long as both are signed and the unique Identifier remains constant.

You need to sign in to Xcode (via Preferences > Accounts) using an Apple ID. A free Apple ID (as opposed to a paid Developer account) is sufficient for [signing code to run locally](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).

In your project settings, under the "Signing and Capabilities" tab; select:

- Automatically manage signing
- Your personal team
- Signing certificate: Development

It's also possible to code sign outside of Xcode using `codesign`, but I'm unsure how this works with an Apple ID.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give "Full Disk Access" to XCode:

```
System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Full Disk Access->Add(+) [Applications-XCode]
```

Comment: Well that might work when starting a program in the actual terminal but doesn't work when starting a program in Xcode.

Comment: I did, same result

Comment: I added both with no results